# Car manual recommends ACEA A3/B4 oil, service personal put ACEA A3/B3. Is this a big deal? Will the car break down?

Tags: oil, oil-change, opel

**2007 Opel Vivaro**

2.0 CDTI (Diesel) no DPF

Milage: 220 000 km

They used Kroon Oil emperol diesel 10W-40:

```
ACEA A3/B3
API SL/CF
MB 229.1
VW 501.01/505.00
```

https://www.kroon-oil.com/en/catalogue/product/252/emperol-diesel-10w-40/582/

### ACEA Engine Oil Specifications:

**ACEA A3/B3:** Stable, stay-in-grade Engine Oil intended for use in Passenger Car & Light Duty Van Gasoline & Diesel Engines and/or for extended drain intervals where specified by the engine manufacturer, and/or for year-round use of Low Viscosity Oils, and/or for severe operating conditions as defined by the Engine Manufacturer.

**ACEA A3/B4:** Stable, stay-in-grade Engine Oil intended for use in Passenger Car & Light Duty Van Gasoline & DI Diesel Engines, but also suitable for applications described under A3/B3.

source: https://www.oilspecifications.org/acea.php

### Is this a big deal? Should i change to oil immediately, or ACEA A3/B3 oil is fine till the next oil change?

Comment: What is the difference between the two oils? Ie what does B4 and B3 mean...

Comment: I added the oil spec info, to the question.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to change it immediately IMO.

The main difference between B3 and B4 is that the TBN number is higher for B4, which gives more capability of neutralizing acidic contaminants in long-oil-life or high-performance situations.

Whether you need to make the next oil change sooner (and how much sooner) is hard to say. It depends a lot on the vehicle usage and your driving style, and the quality of fuel you use (e.g. low sulphur).

Comment: I use this car mostly on motorway ( 120 km/h stable ) for long trips, i believe this should be ideal for these engines. This is a van, so i dont drive it like it is a F1 car. I am planning to do a 6000 km of driving to Spain and then back to Hungary in the next month.

Comment: Just to give a simple answer - no, the car probably won't break down because of this. It *might* experience higher wear until the next oil change due to increased corrosion, but it will likely be negligible over the entire lifetime of the engine, compared to other factors.

Comment: Is it possible to mix in some sort of additive to improve the overall quality of the oil? Maybe an additive which helps with blocking corrosion?